# Storing NSDictionary in permanent memory NSUserDefaults throws setValue:forUndefinedKey

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, dictionary, nsuserdefaults

I'm trying to optimize my app since the loading time seems to be very slow. Right now I'm working on a newsfeed. The first thing I'm doing is saving a Dictionary of [followingId : followingPFUser] with the id and the PFUser that corresponds to that userId. For some reasons it gives me this error when I run the function :

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<_TtGCSs29_NativeDictionaryStorageOwnerSSCSo6PFUser_ 0x13f5a5440> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key 2NWK7vm8cK.'
```

I think there's something wrong with the dictionary but I couldn't figure out. This is my code :

```
func updateFollowing(){
        if self.followedUsers.count > 0{
            print("found some data")
            let getPeopleFollowedByUser = PFQuery(className: "Followers")
            getPeopleFollowedByUser.whereKey("following", equalTo: (PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId!)!)
            getPeopleFollowedByUser.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (followingObjects, error) -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                    for followingObject in followingObjects! {

                        let followed = followingObject.objectForKey("followed") as! String
                        var duplicate : Bool = false
                        for (userId, user) in self.followedUsers {
                            if followed == userId as! String {
                                duplicate = true
                            }
                        }
                        if (!duplicate){
                        let followedInfoQuery = PFUser.query()!
                        followedInfoQuery.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock({ (user, error ) -> Void in
                            if error == nil {
                                if let user = user as? PFUser{
                                self.followedUsers.setValue(user, forKey: followed)
                                }
                            }else{
                                print(error)
                            }
                        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(self.followedUsers, forKey: "followedUsers")
                        })
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    print(error)
                }
            })

        }else{
            print("No data saved")
            var users : NSDictionary = [String : PFUser]()
            if let permanentList = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("followedUsers") as? [String : PFUser] {
                users = permanentList
            }
            if users.count > 0 {
                for (userId, user) in users {
                    self.followedUsers.setValue(user, forKey: userId as! String)
                }
            }
            let getPeopleFollowedByUser = PFQuery(className: "Followers")
            getPeopleFollowedByUser.whereKey("following", equalTo: (PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId!)!)

            do{
                let followingObjects = try getPeopleFollowedByUser.findObjects()
                for followingObject in followingObjects {
                    let followed = followingObject.objectForKey("followed") as! String
                    let followedInfoQuery = PFUser.query()!

                    do{
                        let user = try followedInfoQuery.getObjectWithId(followed) as! PFUser
                        print(user)
                        self.followedUsers.setValue(user, forKey: followed)
                    }catch let err{
                        print(err)
                    }
                }
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(self.followedUsers, forKey: "followedUsers")
            }catch let err{
                print(err)
            }


        }
    }
```

Please let me know if you see anything that might be causing the problem!
Thanks!

EDIT : I followed the error on the debug and apparently it crashes on this line :

```
self.followedUsers.setValue(user, forKey: followed)
```

I tried changing it to `self.followedUser[followed] = user` or `self.followedUsers.setObject(user, forKey: followed)` but it won't build with any of those two.

Comment: It looks like the error is occurring in one of the `setValue` calls.  What is `self.followedUsers`?

Comment: Either userId or followed ends up being an invalid key, which causes the exception. You should set a breakpoint and inspect each key to determine which causes the crash.

Answer (score 0):

First (per @JAL) you are incorrectly setting your dictionary `self.followedUsers`. You should be doing either `self.followedUsers[followed] = user` or `self.followedUsers.setObject(user, forKey: followed)`

Second, `NSUserDefaults` can only store certain types of data. From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000318-SW4):

> The NSUserDefaults class provides convenience methods for accessing
>   common types such as floats, doubles, integers, Booleans, and URLs. A
>   default object must be a property list, that is, an instance of (or
>   for collections a combination of instances of): NSData, NSString,
>   NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary. If you want to store any
>   other type of object, you should typically archive it to create an
>   instance of NSData.

So your error is due to you attempting to save a dictionary which contains `Followers` for values which is not one of those classes.

Comment: How can you deduce this information from the question?  The OP hasn't even shown us what `self.followedUsers` is.

Comment: @JAL OP is setting `self.followedUsers.setValue(user, forKey: followed)` which comes from a query that produces `Followers` objects.

Comment: Yes, but the if `self.followedUsers` is a dictionary `setValue` will cause a crash.  The OP should be using `setObject`.  Additionally, how do you know `Followers` is not `NSCoding`-compliant?

Comment: @JAL It doesn't matter if `Followers` is `NSCoding` compliant, it's not part of the property list so it can't be stored in `NSUserDefaults`. But it does look like you're right that there is another error with setting the dictionary object/keys.

Comment: You can encode non-property list objects as data and store them in `NSUserDefaults`.  It's abuse of the plist, but it's possible.

Comment: Well yeah, that's what it says at the end of my quote. But as-is it would crash (if it got to that point, I revised my answer to include the issue with the dictionary setting)

Comment: This is how I initialize my followedUsers : var followedUsers : NSDictionary = [String:PFUser]() . So I can't really store a PFUser in a dictionary saved in the permanent memory? I'm just trying to find a way so that I don't have to reload the followedUsers objects every time I need it sinceI use it a lot. Do you guys have any other suggestions? Thanks for the help

Comment: Also this is the line that makes it crash : self.followedUsers.setValue(user, forKey: followed) and if I change it to self.followedUsers["\(followed)"] = user  there's an error that says "Cannot assign through subscript: subscript is get-only"

Comment: My first comment fixes your crash bug. As for storing your users, you might consider looking into other ways to store those files, but deficiently look into `NSCoding`, as once you implement that you can save the dictionary to a file or `NSUserDefaults` using `NSData`.

Comment: Oh, to fix the new issue, change your `let` to `var followedUsers`

Comment: `followUsers` is already a var. using                         `self.followedUsers.setObject(user, forKey: followed)` throws an error  "Value of type 'NSDictionary' has no member 'setObject'